# Integral as the sum of integrals in its subsets (related to Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" proof of Theorem 3-13)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

### Motivation:

In Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" proof of Change of Variable in Integration - Theorem 3-13 (p. 68). He mentions, in a part of the proof, that:
\begin{equation}
\sum_S \int_{g^{-1}(\text{int}S)} f \circ g |\det g'| \le \int_{g^{-1}(V)} f \circ g |\det g'|
\end{equation}

where $V$ is a rectangle and $S$ are all the subrectangles contained in a partition of $V$. And $\text{int}S$ is the interior of this subrectangle. Where $f$ is integrable and $g$ is a 1-1 continuos differentiable function.

---

### Question

*Why do we need the above inequality? Because I am of the impression that the equality would always hold in the above equation.*

---

### My take on the problem

In more general terms, I am of the impression that for any integrable funciton $h$, given an open set $A$ and open subsets $G_i$ such that $B = (A -\cup_i G_i)$ has measure 0,  than:
\begin{equation}
\int_A h = \sum_i \int_{G_i} h
\end{equation}

*(tentative) Proof.*
Assume that we define an admissible open cover to each $G_i$, and define $\Phi_i$ a partition of the unit subordinate to this open cover (the existance of such partition is given by theorem 3-11 of the same book). By the definition of integrable in the extended sense (p.65 of the same book):
\begin{equation}
\int_{G_i} h = \sum_{\phi_i \in \Phi_i} \int_{G_i}\phi_i h
\end{equation}

Now, the set $B = (A -\cup_i G_i)$ has measure 0 and hence can be covered with closed rectangles ${R_1, R_2, \cdots}$ with total volume smaller than any $\epsilon$. For each of these rectangles, we can define an open set inside $A$ covering $R_j$, and associate a function $\psi_j$, such that this function is zero outside of $R_j$, is $C^{\inf}$ and $\sum_j \psi_j(x) = 1$ and $0 \le \psi_j(x) \le 1$ for every $x \in B$. Similarly to theorem 3-11 of the same book.

It follow that $(\cup_i \Phi_i) \cup (\cup_j \psi_j)$ is a partition of the unit subordinate to a admissible cover of $A$ and hence, by definition:
\begin{equation}
\int_{A} h = \sum_i \sum_{\phi_i \in \Phi_i} \int_{G_i}\phi_i h + \sum_j  \int_{R_j}\psi_j h
\end{equation}
However, we can made the volume of $R_j$ arbitrarily small. And, hence:
\begin{equation}
\int_{A} h = \sum_i \sum_{\phi_i \in \Phi_i} \int_{G_i}\phi_i h = \sum_i \int_{G}h 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, the equality does hold.

I think Spivak's thought process was like this:

1. He assumed that the function $f$ is positive.
2. Then the inequality would pretty much "obviously" hold due to adding only positive points
3. Having proven the fact for positive functions, we can write any $f$ as a difference of its positive and negative part and be done.

Although statements 2 and 3 are not actually obvious and require rigorous proof (as everything else does), they are quite intuitive and at the same time sufficient to prove our fact.
(*Yeah, Spivak did leave out a lot details in many parts of "Calculus on Manifolds".*)